# Installing fftw-3.3.7

Tags: fftw, mpich

I have installed mpich in my laptop with ubuntu 18.04. I have been trying to install fftw-3.3.7. Wile configuring I have used following command

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/fftw MPICC=mpicc CC=gcc --enable-type-prefix --with-gcc --enable-mpi F77=gfortran F90=gfortran --with-g77-wrappers LDFLAGS="-L/opt/mpich/lib" MPILIBS="-L/opt/mpich/lib -lmpi" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/mpich/include "
```

I am getting error as

```
configure: error: could not find mpi library for --enable-mpi
```

I have checked echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it shows

```
:/opt/mpich/lib
```

I have also checked path of installed mpich using `which mpicc`
it shows :

```
/opt/mpich/bin
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: if the below solution worked, as you seem to indicate, please tick it as answer. best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/mpich/bin CC=mpicc F77=mpif77 F90=mpif90 \ 
  ./configure --prefix=/opt/fftw --enable-mpi --with-g77-wrappers
```

would be more the correct command. You are mixing environment variables and configure options. Environment variables needs to be assigned before `./configure`. Also `--enable-type-prefix --with-gcc` both are meaningless with `fftw3`'s configure script.

But please help me understand, why one would want to have their own build instead of using the distribution's. After all, that's why we install distributions?

`sudo apt -y install libmpich-dev`

Would have solved all your issues. I undertand the specific `fftw` build. It's a performance issue. But `mpich2`?

Comment: Thanks, some people initially suggested me to install it separately. I was following instruction as given in the link http://pajarito.materials.cmu.edu/rollett/Mac-software-hints.html

Comment: If it worked for u, please don't forget to accept the answer